# To find minimal polynomial of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $T_{1} : V \rightarrow V$ and $T_{2} : W \rightarrow W$ be linear transformations whose minimal polynomials are given by $f_{1}(x)=x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$ and $f_{2}(x)=x^{4}-x^{2}-2$. Let $T: V \bigoplus W \rightarrow V \bigoplus W$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(v,w)=(T_{1}(v),T_{2}(w))$ for $ (v,w) \in V \bigoplus W$ and let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$ . Then,
>   1) deg$f(x)=7$
>   2)deg$f(x)=5$
>   3) nullity$(T)=1$
>   4)nullity$(T)=0$.

what i know is minimal polynomial of $T$ will be $lcm \{ f_{1}(x),f_{2}(x)\}=lcm\{(x+1)(x^{2}+1),(x^{2}+1)(x^{2}-2)\}=(x+1)(x^{2}+1)(x^{2}-2)$ is it correct? and how to comment on nullity?

Comment: Can you say what you’ve managed to do or what your thoughts are? If you are already working with direct sums and with minimal polynomials, you should be able to do better than just post the assignment and ask us to walk you through it...

Comment: Sorry I didn't add what I had done. I've added it above now.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the minimal polynomial with no factor of the form $x^k$ then cant you deduce the nullity of an operator?

Comment: yeah, got it thanks